# How do I access an object I've instantiated in my main method from another method?

Tags: java

I'm sure I'm missing something silly, here is my code:

```
public class clearBlankGrid {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Monster myMonster = new Monster(10,10,5,5,1);
        MonsterGUI myGUI = new MonsterGUI(myMonster);

        if (myMonster.getRows() > 0) {   
            // 0 = North, 1 = East, 2 = South, 3 = West
            myMonster.setFacing(3);
            myMonster.setIcon();
        }

    }

    public static void keepClearing() {

        myMonster.isGridCleared(); // Cannot find symbol 'myMonster'

    }

}
```

Comment: I made myMonster a static member, as suggested by everyone. I'm not sure how I managed to forget that, but thanks to everyone for the help! You've saved my hair from being pulled out. :)

Comment: Eventually though you're going to want to get this code out of main and instead put it in a non-static method of a proper class. The main method should be as simple as possible; basically it sets up the program's objects and then turns them on and then steps back, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myMonster` needs to be a static member if you want to access it in the `keepClearing` method (which is static).

Note: For reference you could also avoid making the `Monster` member static by actually instantiating your `clearBlankGrid` class. `Monster` can then be an instance variable of `clearBlankGrid` which means the `keepClearing` method no longer has to be static.

```
public class clearBlankGrid {

   private Monster myMonster;
   private MonsterGUI myGUI;

   public void run() {
       myMonster = new Monster(10,10,5,5,1);
       myGUI = new MonsterGUI(myMonster);

       if (myMonster.getRows() > 0) {   
            // 0 = North, 1 = East, 2 = South, 3 = West
            myMonster.setFacing(3);
            myMonster.setIcon();
        }
   }

    public void keepClearing() {
        myMonster.isGridCleared();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        clearBlankGrid blankGrid = new clearBlankGrid();
        blankGrid.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't name the main delegation method "run" if the class isn't Runnable. I tend to name the the main delegation method "process", "execute" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the object in a static field.

Comment: After some research, you seem to have put me on the right track. I had previously tried putting the object outside of main, but I spaced the "static" bit. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Make `myMonster` a `static` class member:

```
public class clearBlankGrid {

    private static Monster myMonster;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        myMonster = new Monster(10,10,5,5,1);
        // ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class clearBlankGrid {

    // I made this static because you access it via a static method.  
    // If you make it a class member, as Greg Hewgill suggested, then 
    // change the method that uses it to be non-static
    private static  Monster myMonster = new Monster(10,10,5,5,1);


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MonsterGUI myGUI = new MonsterGUI(myMonster);

        if (myMonster.getRows() > 0) {   
            // 0 = North, 1 = East, 2 = South, 3 = West
            myMonster.setFacing(3);
            myMonster.setIcon();
        }

    }

    public static void keepClearing() {

        myMonster.isGridCleared(); // Cannot find symbol 'myMonster'

    }
}
```